# Calculus Infinite Limit Proof

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I'm trying to prove:

> $\lim_{x\rightarrow5^+} \frac{3}{(x-5)(x-2)}=\infty$

Let $M>0$. Choose $\delta =$

Assume $0<x-5<\delta$. Show $\frac{3}{(x-5)(x-2)}>M$

$\frac{3}{(x-5)(x-2)}>M$

$\frac{3}{x-5}>M(x-2)$

$x-5<\frac{3}{M(x-2)}$

I'm getting stuck here, I can't find $\delta$ and I've been working for hours on this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm trying to generalize this for a bigger theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next step: Since $x-5>0,$ $x-2>3$ and thus $0<\frac1{x-2}<\frac13.$

Answer (score 0):

For the chosen $M>0$ take $\delta=\frac{2}{M+\sqrt{M^2+4M}}$. Then for $x \in (5,5+\delta)$, $x<5+\delta\Rightarrow \frac{1}{x-5}>\frac{1}{\delta}$ and $x-2< 3+\delta<3+3\delta\Rightarrow \frac{3}{x-2}>\frac{1}{1+\delta}$. Combining $\frac{3}{(x-5)(x-2)}>\frac{1}{\delta(\delta+1)}=M$ (verify the last calculation).